# ASP.NET Core 3.1 web application throws error 500.30 when run on IIS Express, but not when using dotnet watch run

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, iis-express

When running my application from Visual Studio 2019 on IIS Express the web page gives error 500.30 and in the output it says,

```
Exception thrown: 'System.NullReferenceException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
```

However, when running it in a terminal using `dotnet watch run` the page runs without errors and displays correctly.

I've tried running the debugger and the error is always thrown on this line,

```
CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
```

after my ConfigureSerives Method below completes

```
// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public static void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllers();
            services.AddRouting();
        }
```

I've also tried repairing my Visual Studio 2019 as well as reinstalling .NET 3.1.100 SDK with no luck.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Edit:

I had to publish the program and then run the .exe, but this was the output I got

```
crit: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[6]
      Application startup exception
System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: C:\Users\ray.kochenderfer\Documents\public\hub\public\
   at Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.PhysicalFileProvider..ctor(String root, ExclusionFilters filters)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.PhysicalFileProvider..ctor(String root)
   at QualityHub.Startup.Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env) in C:\Users\ray.kochenderfer\repos\quality_hub\Startup.cs:line 49
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor, Boolean wrapExceptions)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureBuilder.Invoke(Object instance, IApplicationBuilder builder)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<Build>b__0(IApplicationBuilder builder)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass13_0.<UseStartup>b__2(IApplicationBuilder app)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters.MiddlewareFilterBuilderStartupFilter.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<Configure>g__MiddlewareFilterBuilder|0(IApplicationBuilder builder)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.HostFilteringStartupFilter.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<Configure>b__0(IApplicationBuilder app)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostService.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Unhandled exception. System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: C:\Users\ray.kochenderfer\Documents\public\hub\public\
   at Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.PhysicalFileProvider..ctor(String root, ExclusionFilters filters)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.PhysicalFileProvider..ctor(String root)
   at QualityHub.Startup.Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env) in C:\Users\ray.kochenderfer\repos\quality_hub\Startup.cs:line 49
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor, Boolean wrapExceptions)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureBuilder.Invoke(Object instance, IApplicationBuilder builder)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<Build>b__0(IApplicationBuilder builder)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass13_0.<UseStartup>b__2(IApplicationBuilder app)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters.MiddlewareFilterBuilderStartupFilter.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<Configure>g__MiddlewareFilterBuilder|0(IApplicationBuilder builder)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.HostFilteringStartupFilter.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<Configure>b__0(IApplicationBuilder app)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostService.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.RunAsync(IHost host, CancellationToken token)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.RunAsync(IHost host, CancellationToken token)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.Run(IHost host)
   at QualityHub.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\ray.kochenderfer\repos\quality_hub\Program.cs:line 16
```

Comment: What is the version of visual studio..,?

Comment: Do you have a custom `CreateHostBuilder`?

Comment: Visual studio version: 16.4.1 and I do not have a custom CreateHostBuilder

Comment: Running net core 3.0 project on visual studio 16.3.9 without issue, after upgrade to 16.4.1 now i have the same issue. If i have any progress i will report back here.

Comment: Thank you! I ran the program later at home on two different computers and it ran without issue on both IIS Express and dontnet CLI, so I believe it is an issue with Visual Studio.

Comment: Yes, it is related to visual studio. For now i am running under kestrel on the local machine

Comment: It also seems to be related to ASP.NET Core 2.2. I downgraded it to 2.1.7 and the program ran fine then.

Comment: I just updated ASP.NET Core back to 2.2.0 and it seems to be working now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is [github issue](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/17614) about this problem.

> Using 2.x versions of Microsoft.Extensions.* and
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.* packages in an ASP.NET Core 3.0/3.1 project is
>   *not supported.

In my case i was depending on nuget package which was depending on Microsoft.AspNetCore 2.x.x. After removing the nuget the project ran without issues under IIS Express.

If anyone is still having this issue, you can try to remove dependencies with version 2.x because they are automatically resolved from the SDK.

Comment: This is a strange issue. On my locall IIS (windows 10) i can deploy my project and it runs without errors, on my production server (windows server 2012) it throws this error once i configure sql settings in `appsettings.production.json` before changing those sql settings, at least the home page could open

Comment: @CharlesOkwuagwu I think your problem may be completely different. Maybe the server does can't find the server where the database is hosted.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem with IISExpress. The only way I could get ride of the 500.30 error, was to run the application in OutOfProcess mode.

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <AspNetCoreHostingModel>OutOfProcess</AspNetCoreHostingModel>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: This worked for me.  I couldn't run on IIS and this fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

This can be due to any number of reasons and without logging, it will be very difficult to determine what's going on.

Add a web.config with similar configuration. stdoutLogEnabled will generate logs that can help further troubleshoot the issue, especially if it's specific to IIS Express.

```
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet"
                  arguments=".\MyApp.dll"
                  stdoutLogEnabled="false"
                  stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout"
                  hostingModel="inprocess" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/aspnet-core-module?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: I added the web.config file and ran the program with the same issue. The stdout log was also empty.

Comment: Bit late... try adding  stdoutLogEnabled="true" to get stdout.. but make sure you have logs folder

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue. The issue had something to do with ASP.NET Core Version 2.2.0 interacting with Visual Studio 2019 Version 16.4.1. I Downgraded ASP.NET Core to Version 2.1.7 then updated it back to Version 2.2.0. This seems to have fixed the issue.

Edit: This only temporarily fixed the issue. However, downgrading to 2.1.7 seems to be working reliably.